# Unable to receive environment variables in Golang and Windows 10

Tags: go

I have set a couple of environment variables in Windows 10, but I cannot receive them in Golang and I just can't find out why.

[image]

```
dbUser := os.Getenv("DB_USER")
dbName := os.Getenv("DB_NAME")
```

[image]

Comment: Can you check the full list by running `set | more` in `cmd.exe`. If they're there, try running your Go binary through the terminal too. You can also try [os.LookupEnv](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#LookupEnv) and print both returned args.

Comment: And here is your standard suggestion from helpdesk: restart your PC :)

Comment: Just checked the list and they are there. Also tried to run it through terminal

Comment: Yeah, it's unclear: https://serverfault.com/questions/8855/how-do-you-add-a-windows-environment-variable-without-rebooting, but this being windows, I would follow @Ain's suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Restarted my pc. Now, it works fine.

Comment: FYI Simply logging out and back in should also work.

Comment: @msanford i don't think that works, at least for me. i needed to restart.

Comment: @AnanRaddad I should have specified that this only works for user-scope environment variables. Unfortunately OP set a system-scope variable. OP, **don't do that** put it in the user scope. Putting it in the global system scope means any app can read them, which is bad for credentials.