# Different Signature HMAC SHA512 Between Hardcoded Secret Key and Stored Secret Key at env file using Golang

Tags: go, environment-variables, hmac, hmacsha512

I want to make some signature using HMAC SHA512 and encoded to string using base64

My message is `POST:/v1.0/debit/payment-host-to-host:gp9HjjEj813Y9JGoqwOeOPWbnt4CupvIJbU1Mmu4a11MNDZ7Sg5u9a:56fa5f4999ad8014de49d7898c1d1d53472569db8999de3c1b752a0dd181e98c:2020-01-01T00:00:00+07:00`

And secret is `fdppqbF5wq7vVegyvsV1CROMv646nJ7A`

If I store my secret key at env, I got
`1sFLy5JqnsaF/fUONKdhWqIysMNfy+j/Pl3ee4C8NiLs3J6Cn2qHjSAqT6aUloPLkNHOY0/GPlAEQsLPKQVt7w==`
as signature

But if I hardcode the secret, I got
`FSlidRHe4ow9qppNifGVQNcdv67lBjgCiP0BHylh+IKXo4fs2rHaGsFNUY0N8t0rPlZs4iAHAOCDklnCccwuJw==`
as signature

I wonder how is it possible? Am I stored it wrong in my env?

Here is the code in golang

```
    stringToSign := "POST:/v1.0/debit/payment-host-to-host:gp9HjjEj813Y9JGoqwOeOPWbnt4CupvIJbU1Mmu4a11MNDZ7Sg5u9a:56fa5f4999ad8014de49d7898c1d1d53472569db8999de3c1b752a0dd181e98c:2020-01-01T00:00:00+07:00"

    secret := "fdppqbF5wq7vVegyvsV1CROMv646nJ7A"
    // secret := os.Getenv("MY_SECRET_KEY")
    sig := hmac.New(sha512.New, []byte(secret)) //secret key hmacsha512
    sig.Write([]byte(stringToSign))
    signature = base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(sig.Sum(nil))
```

And here is my env file

```
MY_SECRET_KEY = fdppqbF5wq7vVegyvsV1CROMv646nJ7A
#MY_SECRET_KEY = "fdppqbF5wq7vVegyvsV1CROMv646nJ7A"
```

Comment: `1sFLy5...` is the HMAC when an *empty* key is used, see online: https://go.dev/play/p/JxTQnzE8ikE. Obviously you have less of an HMAC problem than a problem reading your key from the .env file. Check if the environment variable is set, try restarting the IDE and/or the computer, etc. See e.g. [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48131439/9014097) for a similar problem (on Windows).